# C/C++ 'continue' Equivalent in VB6

Tags: c, vb6

Is there a VB6 equivalent to the C/C++ 'continue' keyword?

In C/C++, the command 'continue' starts the next iteration of the loop.

Of course, other equivalents exist.  I could put the remaining code of the loop in an if-statement.  Alternatively, I could use a goto. (Ugh!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no equivalent in VB6, but later versions of VB do introduce this keyword.

Perhaps you can restructure your code to either add an if statement or have the loop just call a function that you can return from.

Answer (score 8):

VB6 has no continue statement for loops. You have to emulate it using goto, if, or another loop.

```
//VB.net
do
    if condition then continue do
    ...
loop
//VB6 equivalent (goto)
do
    if condition then goto continue_do
    ...
continue_do:
loop
//VB6 equivalent (if)
do
    if not condition then
        ...
    endif
loop
```

You can not use "exit while" in VB6. But you can use goto.

```
While condition

    if should_skip then goto mycontinue

    'code

    if should_break then goto outloop

   mycontinue:

Wend

outloop:
```

Answer (score 7):

Sadly there is no Continue if VB6 - this was new in VB 2005 I believe.

I wouldn't always be afraid of goto statements - that's effectively what the Continue is, but without the need for a labelled line after the loop. As long as your goto statements don't jump very far, they will always be readable, and it is probably the most elegant solution to this problem.

Nesting another if/then/else inside a for loop is actually HARDER to read and maintain later than a nice simple goto (with a comment on the goto line saying something like "' read as Continue For").

Good luck!

Comment: In other words, "goto only considered harmful when there are no better alternatives". A sentiment I agree with completely. (In early versions of BASIC a "while" loop was constructed with IF-THEN-GOTO, and it wasn't so bad as long as your loops weren't too big.)

Answer (score 2):

I´m an idiot :P thanks   MarkJ

```
   For index As Integer = 1 To 10
        If  index=9 Then
            Continue For
        End If
   'some cool code'
    Next
```

No sorry only for .net.
 I think you have to use goto, I know it looks ‘cleaner’ to use a continue but there is nothing wrong with going the if route.

wrong.

```
 Continue:
     For index As Integer = 1 To 10
                If index=9 Then
                  GoTo Continue
                End If
    'some cool code'
     Next
```

corrected(?)

```
     For index = 1 To 10
      If index=9 Then
       GoTo Continue 
      End If    
    'some cool code'
Continue:
     Next
```

hate vb

Comment: Your label is in the wrong place. That would restart the loop from 1 every time - infinite loop. In my opinion it's best to put it just before the Next. 

In fact you've got a serious case of air code ;) You've included the "As Integer" in the VB6 For statement, which is not valid VB6, and you've used i and index for the variable name in both your VB.NET and your VB6.

Comment: Apparently didn't get into VBA6 (Office 2010), either.

Comment: Using goto to simulate a continue is a good example of programming IN TO a language instead of just in it, as Steve McConnell would put it.